# Is there a relationship between orthomorphisms of groups and orthomorphisms on Riesz spaces ?

Tags: group-theory

Is there a relationship between orthomorphisms of groups and orthomorphisms on Riesz spaces ?

Comment: I have never come across the term "orthomorphisms of groups" before: Apparently, "this is a transformation which when applied to the addition table of an abelian group yields a square which is orthogonal to the original square." -- [Johnson, Dulmage, Mendelsohn, *Orthomorphisms of groups and orthogonal latin squares. I*, Canad. J. Math. 13(1961), 356-372](http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1961-031-7). In case anyone else is wondering. The above paper introduces the notion, with the goal of creating mutually orthogonal Latin squares, in the sense of the 36-officers problem.